# Not able to retrieve data from Shared Preferences when App Life Cycle is Resumed Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm using shared preferences to store some data but I need to retrieve that data when App Life Cycle is resumed but getting empty list when app is restarted then I'm getting all data from shared preferences.

Here is code snippet

```
 @override
 void initState() {
 WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
 super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
super.dispose();
}

@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async{ 
      await  homeController.getPrefsData();
    
   });
}
```

}

And my Home Controller code

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {
List<String> users = ['User 1', 'User 2'];



@override
void onInit() {
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
  
  await setPrefsData();
});
super.onInit();
}

Future<void> setPrefsData() {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('allUsers', jsonEncode(users));
  
}
}



Future<void> getPrefsData() {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final stringifiedData = prefs.getString('allUsers');
  log('STRINGIFIED DATA::: ${stringifiedData}'); //Empty when called from App Life Cycle
}
}
```

Comment: How did you code the setString part?

Comment: I've updated my code. You can check it out

Comment: Did you miss putting async into getPrefsData while writing your question? (Future<void> getPrefsData() async { final prefs = await....)

Comment: Yeah I forgot to put async in question but in my code I've async and result is still the same

Comment: Have you checked that jsonEncode(messages) has the value you want?

Comment: It is actually List<String> users that is initialized in my controller but mistakenly I wrote messages so yeah it has value and correctly inserted in shared preferences

Answer (score 0):

`List<String>` is not a **JSON** type.

You can use **SharedPreferences**' `setStringList` method.

```dart
Future<void> setPrefsData() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setStringList('allUsers', users);
}
```

Comment: In older version of shared preferences you can store list of string as string by encoding but issue is not storing List<String> in shared preferences but issue is it is not retrieved when App Life Cycle is resumed.